# Invoke command and outputting to a csv file

Tags: powershell

The script works but not able to throw result into a csv.

My output :

```
"PSComputerName","RunspaceId","PSShowComputerName","Length"
"Server02","cecee03a-e45f-4b77-85e4-dfade4c30e78","True","0"
"Server02","cecee03a-e45f-4b77-85e4-dfade4c30e78","True","229"
"Server02","cecee03a-e45f-4b77-85e4-dfade4c30e78","True","0"
"Server02","cecee03a-e45f-4b77-85e4-dfade4c30e78","True","0"
```

My desired output:

```
Computer Name,Last Exit Code
Server02,0
Server122,99
Port closed or computer unreachable removing  server33
```

Script :

```
$installs = Import-Csv "C:\TEMP\agent.csv"
$results = Foreach ($Singleitem in $installs) {
    try {
       Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Singleitem.name -ScriptBlock { cmd /c C:\tmp\agent.bat ;[pscustomobject]@{Lastexitcode = $lastexitcode} } -ErrorAction 'Stop'
    }
    catch {
        [pscustomobject]@{
           
             "ComputerName" = "Port closed or computer unreachable removing $($Singleitem.name)"
        }
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\agentinstall.csv" -Encoding 'UTF8' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I think you should replace the $singleitem.name to $singleitem.computername. Do not leave additional space in-between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To get meaningful CSV output, you need to make sure that all output objects are of the same type or at least have the properties of interest in common.

  - The *first* output object *locks in* what properties are used / columns are the result.
  - It looks like your `cmd /c C:\tmp\agent.bat` call (which can normally be simplified to just `C:\tmp\agent.bat`) is producing *stdout output*, which means that a *string* is output as the first object, resulting in the CSV output you saw (`[string]` instances have just *one* property, `.Length`; the other properties are an artifact of PowerShell's remoting).
- Therefore, you must *suppress* the batch-file output; `*>$null` is a convenient way to silence *all* streams (in the case of batch files, as with any *external program*, there are only *two*: stdout and stderr)
- By targeting computers *one by one*, in *sequence*, you're forgoing the built-in *parallel execution* that PowerShell offers when you pass *multiple* computer names to [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Invoke-Command)'s `-ComputerName` property.

  - However, doing so is at odds with `-ErrorAction Stop`, as an error on *one* machine would then stop processing on *all*.
  - By omitting `-ErrorAction Stop` and using redirection `2>&1` instead, you can send errors through the pipeline for further processing, and you can use `$_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` to test in a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) script block whether the input object at hand is an *error* or *data* from the remote call.
  - If the input object is an error, `$_.CategoryInfo.TargetName` contains the name of the computer that was targeted.

To put it all together:

```
$installs = Import-Csv C:\TEMP\agent.csv
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $installs.name -ScriptBlock { 
  cmd /c C:\tmp\agent.bat *>$null # Discard the batch file's output.
  [pscustomobject] @{ LastExitCode = $LASTEXITCODE } 
} 2>&1 | 
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) {
      [pscustomobject] @{
        ComputerName = "Port closed or computer unreachable removing $($_.CategoryInfo.TargetName)"
        LastExitCode = 'n/a'
      }
    }
    else {
      [pscustomobject] @{
        ComputerName = $_.PSComputerName
        LastExitCode = $_.LastExitCode
      } 
    }
  } | 
  Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\agentinstall.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```